# Extend line plot by scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

From the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

np.random.seed(42)
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(30), freq='D')
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col2': data},index=days)
print(df.head())
                                 col2
2019-10-22 09:35:28.766634    52
2019-10-23 09:35:28.766634    93
2019-10-24 09:35:28.766634    15
2019-10-25 09:35:28.766634    72
2019-10-26 09:35:28.766634    61
```

I want to plot the first half as line and the second half as scatter plot.

The code

```
first_half = df.loc[date_today:(date_today + timedelta(15))]
second_half = df.loc[(date_today + timedelta(15)):days[-1]]
ax = first_half.plot()
ax.scatter(second_half.index, second_half.col2)
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

however, only generates the line plot:

[image: graph]

How can I get the intended result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following code to produce what I think is the effect you want, but
it doesn't use `scatter`. Also, it doesn't answer your question on why your code doesn't work!

```py
first_half = df.loc[date_today:(date_today + timedelta(15))]
second_half = df.loc[(date_today + timedelta(15)):days[-1]]
ax = first_half.plot()
#ax.scatter(second_half.index, second_half.col2)
second_half.plot(linestyle='None', marker='o', ax=ax)
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Prasanth